# Components of $X$ are connected disjoint subspaces whose union is $X$ s.t each nonempty connected subspace intersects only one of them

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Hi i am reading Topology by Munkres and have one doubt in the proof of **theorem 25.1**. There it says

> By the result just proved $A_x\subset C$

I am unable to understand the above quoted statement. The theorem states that :*The components of $X$ are connected disjoint subspaces of $X$, such that each nonempty connected subspace of $X$ intersects only one of them.*

I don't know how the result just proved above gives us $A_x\subset C$
? For reference i am attaching the screenshot of the theorem's proof where i have highlighted the part in which i have problem. Btw only the highlighted part i am unable to understand everything else is fine.

[image: Scrennshot 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Munkres says in the previous paragraph, a connected subspace only intersects exactly one component. And $A_x$ surely intersects $C$, since they both contain the point $x \in C$. Hence $A_x$ does only intersect $C$, and since the equivalence classes $\mathcal C$ partition $X$, we have $A_x \subset C$.

In symbols

$$
A_x = A_x \cap X = A_x \cap \bigcup_{S \in \mathcal C}S = \bigcup_{S \in \mathcal C} A_x \cap S = A_x \cap C,
$$

as $A_x \cap S = \varnothing$ for all $S \neq C$ in $\mathcal S$. Hence $A_x= A_x \cap C$ and so $A_x \subset C$.

Comment: Ok i understand the mathematical reasoning but in the explanatory part at the end line you have written since the equivalence classes $\mathcal C$ partition $X$, we have $A_x\subset C$. How does the fact that equivalence classes partition X imply that $A_x\subset C$?

Comment: That is precisely the part I proceeded to do in symbols. Note that what I said is that since $A_x$ does only intersect $C$ out of all equivalence classes *and* such classes partition $A$, we have $A_x \subset C$. For the computation it suffices to use that the equivalence classes cover $X$, I didn't use that their union was disjoint.

Comment: Yeah you didn't use that their union was disjoint. Instead you have used the distributive property of intersections and unions over each other . Thanks